# Android Google Services new configuration file questions

Tags: android, json, google-analytics, google-cloud-messaging, google-play-services

I'm a little bit confused with the new Google Services and it's configuration files. With the latest version of the Google Play Services library we need to generate a JSON configuration file which provides service-specific information for our app and applying its gradle plugin it reads and loads that configuration file ([see guide](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/)). Within that file we have something like this if we enable GCM and Analytics:

```
...
  "services": {
    "analytics_service": {
      "status": 2,
      "analytics_property": {
        "tracking_id": "UA-XXXXXXXX-X"
      }
    },
    "cloud_messaging_service": {
      "status": 2,
      "apns_config": []
    }
...
```

I have two related questions:

1. Why do we need to put our `tracking_id` there if we already need it to instantiate our Analytics tracker? e.g:

   ```
   mTracker = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(context).newTracker(R.xml.analytics_release);
   ```

   Where `R.xml.analytics_release` contains again another `ga_trackingId` having two references to `UA-XXXXXXXX-X`.
2. In the GCM section what implies to have the `status` property activated (`status: 2`) or deactivated (`status: 1`)?

I don't really understand the need of this configuration file and its implications. Without it, we will get some warning messages and also having it we need to [add some extra receivers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30164011/812598) in our manifest.