# Google Analytics not communicating to server - AnalyticsReceiver is not registered or is disabled - error

Tags: android, google-analytics, react-native, react-native-firebase, google-analytics-firebase

I have setup react native firebase on my android react-native app to track app hits on analytics. But the hits are not reaching from android emulator. So, I checked the log with `adb logcat` and found out the below warnings and suspect that this might be causing the issue.

```
AnalyticsReceiver is not registered or is disabled. Register the receiver for reliable dispatching on non-Google Play devices. See link for instructions.
CampaignTrackingReceiver is not registered, not exported or is disabled. Installation campaign tracking is not possible. See link for instructions.
AnalyticsService not registered in the app manifest. Hits might not be delivered reliably. See link for instructions.
```

I followed this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30154057/analyticsservice-not-registered-in-the-app-manifest-error) and did some changes to the manifest file.

Modified `AndroidManifest.xml` file:

```
<manifest
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.truuue.truuuerental">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DOWNLOAD_WITHOUT_NOTIFICATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

      <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
                 android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>

      <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
          android:configChanges=
                  "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
          android:label="@string/app_name" />
      <activity
          android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity"
          android:exported="true">
          <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
              <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
              <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
              <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme" />
          </intent-filter>
      </activity>

      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="truuuetenant" android:host="*" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
      <receiver android:name="com.appsflyer.SingleInstallBroadcastReceiver" android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
        </intent-filter>
      </receiver>

       <!-- Optionally, register AnalyticsReceiver and AnalyticsService to support background dispatching on non-Google Play devices -->
      <receiver android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.AnalyticsReceiver"
          android:enabled="true">
          <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.ANALYTICS_DISPATCH" />
          </intent-filter>
      </receiver>
      <service android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.AnalyticsService"
          android:enabled="true"
          android:exported="false"/>

      <!-- Optionally, register CampaignTrackingReceiver and CampaignTrackingService to enable
            installation campaign reporting -->
      <receiver android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingReceiver"
          android:exported="true">
          <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
          </intent-filter>
      </receiver>
      <service android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingService" />

      <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
      <!-- You will only need to add this meta-data tag, but make sure it's a child of application -->
      <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyB3stzerjTZEubg4WqkF1mJeqAB7TcnXj0"/>
      <uses-library
          android:name="org.apache.http.legacy"
          android:required="false" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

But still the error is appearing. Any idea on how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the mail that I recently received from **Google Analytics** team,

> What does “stopped processing” mean?
>
> New data you send to the Google Analytics properties listed above will
>   not be serviced and will therefore, not appear on your reports. This
>   will appear as though you are no longer sending app data to Google
>   Analytics.
>
> What will happen to my Google Analytics properties listed above?
>
> - Reporting access through our UI and API access will remain available for these properties’ historical data until January 31,
>     2020.
> - After our service is fully turned down in February 2020, these legacy properties will no longer be accessible via our Google
>     Analytics UI or API, and the associated data will be deleted from
>     Google Analytics servers. In advance of this turndown, we recommend
>     that you retrieve this historical data through report exports.

**NOTE:** Bottomline, it is advised to follow and use the [Firebase Analytics](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/get-started?platform=android) for reports.